# Can i make polymorphic_url for collection route in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My URL is : `/students/information?name='john'`
In my application, student is model, and information is not a model.

My routes is like this :

```
  resources :students do
    get :information, on: :collection
  end
```

Can i make polymorphic_url for this URL?
In my stuent/index page, i have polymorphic_url like this. (For pagination links )

```
<%=
  polymorphic_url(
    Student,
    name: params[:name]
  ) 
%>
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use `polymorphic_url`? Why not use `information_students_url`? `information_students_url(name: params[:name])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
polymorphic_url([Student, :information], name: params[:name])
```

Comment: Quite frankly thats a really wonky unRESTful route though. You should really just define it as a member path and use ids and not names.